# Как реализовать "большие" сообщения в Azure Queue?

Tags: azure, очередь, azure-storage

Размер сообщения в очереди Azure Queue ограничен 64 КБ. Но там же, в документации есть упоминание больших сообщений:

`Azure поддерживает большие сообщения за счет сочетания очередей и больших двоичных объектов; благодаря этому можно поставить в очередь до 200 ГБ данных на один элемент.`

Не могу найти в документации как именно. Как это реализуется? Как использовать в очереди сообщения больше 64К?

Answer (score 0):

Выше приведенная цитата относится к Blob сообщения (больше "массивы" или на худой конец "файлы", но никак не сообщения). Сообщения ("messages") от Storage Queues ограничены размером 64КБ. Для того чтобы использовать сообщения размером больше чем 64КБ, придется либо имплементировать [Claim Check Pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html) либо пересмотреть выбор транспорта. Например, Azure Service Bus сообщение может быть 256КБ/1МБ в зависимости от уровня сервиса. Плюс такой сервис как Service Bus поддерживает плагины. Одним и таких плагинов создан для решения проблемы с максимальным размером сообщений, [`ServiceBus.AttachmentPlugin`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/servicebus.attachmentplugin). Более об этом плагине [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/claim-check#claim-check-generation-with-service-bus).